# People who discovered God on their own

Tags: sources-mekorot

Chazal give a list of people who discovered God on their own. Does anyone know where this list is? I saw it a while ago but can't recall where.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. A surprisingly good source of info. is Google. A quick google search is a great way to start a search. Hope to see you around the site. :)

Comment: Thanks. I did that before I came here. And thank you for the welcome, :)